# Casperjs ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, npm, phantomjs, casperjs, bots

I tried in many ways to succeed reinstalled OS, packages, changed paths back and forward nothing worked as showed in examples from youtube or other sources.

this is the error when trying to execute the code bellow:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process

phantomjs://platform/path.js:26

when executing code simple example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

Please advise, 
my task is to elaborate a bot, maybe you  know a better environment for such tasks, please advise.

Thank you

[My Node Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r4Aj.png)

Comment: Do you have the `process` module under your `npm_modules` directory?. if not install it using `npm install --save process`

Comment: Thank you David for ur reply, Just installed it, however the problem still persist